# Kingston Airport to Port Antonio routes

Tags: airport-transfer, driving, routes, jamaica

If I rent a car from Kingston Airport to drive to Port Antonio, the road choices include:

1. A3
2. B1: Mountainous Route
3. A4: coastal road.  Longer route

I understand that in general, the condition of the roads is poor.

What is the process / criteria to decide the route?

If you are a local or have traversed any of the routes, please state this and the traversed route in your reply.